# Bulk export PNG from all worksheets in Tableau Desktop

Tags: tableau-api

Does anyone know a way or a 'plugin' that can, at one click, export all worksheets' images.

I have a number of worksheets, and desire to save (export) each of then as PNGs. For now, I do that one after the other. Quite labourious.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can export at once a PDF with all the pages. It may be an alternative to images.

Comment: I'd try this and get back. Thanks @Abdel